# JS/jQuery: recall function that contains all jQuery codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have a problem with js and jQuery, let me explain.

I have a situation which loads a html content dynamically, after this I call a function that contains all my jQuery codes. But why? It's because I need that all the events bound before, works with the new content. So, my problem is, it works but just the first time.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  myfunctions();

});

function myfunctions()
{

  /* It calls datepicker plugin */
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  
  /* It opens a lightbox with the new html content */
  $('.open-popup').click(function() {

    $.popup.open(function() {
    
      callbacks: {
        
        /* It runs when lightbox has just opened */
        open: function() {
          
          myfunctions();
          
        }
      }
      
    });
    
  });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note:

Realize that the cdoe is opening a lightbox and the callback "open" calls again the "myfunctions()", so if has a element with class "datepicker" the plugin is called again to this element. This code works fine in the first time, but if I close the lightbox and open it again doesn't work anymore.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You shoudn´t bind the same event to same element multiple times

Comment: Use [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/): `$(document).on('click', '.open-popup', func);` Running this code once will bind that function to any element with that selector, even if they don't exist yet.

Comment: juvian: can i just unbind all events before call the function again??